# C# - Error with insert into AS400 using ODBC

Tags: c#, insert, odbc

Someone can help me???

I trying to make a app using C# and ODBC iSeries to insert some XMLs informations into AS400.
So, I have a error that I can't undertand and resolve.

*System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0104 - Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: .
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at XmlTransport.AS400Connect.AS400Insert(String strInsert) in J:\Documents\Projetos\Projetos VS2010\XmlTransport\XmlTransport\AS400Connect.cs:line 48*

The line 48 it's my ExecuteNonQuerry command:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=LA400PC;system=LA400PC;uid=SOMEUSER;pwd=SOMEPWD;dbq=QGPL;dftpkglib=QGPL;languageid=ENU;pkg=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;translate=1;signon=1");
            conn.Open();
            try
            {              

                OdbcCommand insertComand = new OdbcCommand(strInsert, conn);
                insertComand.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
```

And I'm trying to insrte this string:

```
INSERT INTO ZSA3837.CONFXMLH VALUES ('26111160500246001479550010000564091205644070', '1', '56409', 20111116, 60500246001479, 97422620000150, 122929.08, 14751.50, 200743.19, 19374.84, 122929.08, 18439.36, 160743.28);
```

I'm trying many thing but can't make works... can anyone help me ???
Thanks

Comment: There is only one semicolon in your insert string. Did you try to remove it?

Comment: :D   LOL...... I forgot the semicolon.... Oh My God!!!!! one hour trying everthing.....

Thanks a lot Steve, it work!

Comment: I would go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400/ and get an as400 connection string.

Answer (score 0):

[AS400 connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400/)

I've had pretty good luck with this.  I think DSN is PC specific so it's probably balking at that.